# Clojure: DSL for CSS

Tags: css, clojure

### Context

CSS lacks things like variables, functions, etc ...

Clojure is great for writing DSLS.

I'm currently already using Clojure+Ring+Compojure for backend; ClojureScript for writing Javascript to interact with Google Closure classes.

I would like to be able to create CSS in Clojure.

## Question

Is there any good Clojure DSL for creating CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at http://clojure-libraries.appspot.com/cat/Web+Server+Libraries and http://clojure.org/libraries, there are what it looks like the options are:

- cssgen - http://github.com/paraseba/cssgen
- clj-style - https://github.com/rathwell/clj-style
- neman.css - http://bitbucket.org/ksojat/neman/
- Gaka - https://github.com/briancarper/gaka

I haven't used any of them, but it looks like you'll probably get the best results with cssgen or clj-style.

Answer (score 9):

I'm a little late to the party here but you might want to checkout [Garden](https://github.com/noprompt/garden). It's a "full featured" Clojure CSS DSL with builtin support for unit arithmetic, color manipulation, media queries and whole lot more. The project is fairly active and issues generally get prompt attention from the maintainer (me!).

Comment: Great looking project!  Glad I don't have to include sass/less/stylus in my clj(s) workflow thanks to it.

Answer (score 0):

Might be these links will help you

http://www.vijaykiran.com/2012/01/11/web-application-development-with-clojure-part-1/

http://clojure.org/libraries

**Enlive** -Html Templating 
**Enlive** is a selector-based (à la CSS) templating library for Clojure,it has two parts: a HTML file and a deftemplate form somewhere in a clj file.

**Sandbar**  -html sessions etc